# How to get CMFEditions "view this revision" working for items that use a BrowserView in Plone

Tags: templates, macros, plone

I have a custom template for news items defined using a BrowserView overriding the default template in Plone's skin layer.  We also have CMFEditions installed.  Trying to view a previous revision results in an error as discussed in this [Plone bug](http://dev.plone.org/plone/ticket/8372).  We're in the process of upgrading to Plone 3.3.6 so the "fix" describe there is in place but I'm still seeing the "view this revision" link and it still results in an error

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 119, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 88, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 42, in call_object
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 313, in __call__
  Module Products.PloneHotfix20110531, line 106, in _patched_bindAndExec
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 350, in _bindAndExec
  Module Products.CMFCore.FSPageTemplate, line 216, in _exec
  Module Products.CacheSetup.patch_cmf, line 51, in FSPT_pt_render
  Module Products.CacheSetup.patch_cmf, line 126, in PT_pt_render
   - Warning: Macro expansion failed
   - Warning: exceptions.KeyError: 'view_macro'
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 271, in __call__
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 891, in do_useMacro
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 536, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 521, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 516, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 957, in do_defineSlot
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 536, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 521, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 516, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 861, in do_defineMacro
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 957, in do_defineSlot
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 536, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 521, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 516, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 949, in do_defineSlot
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 855, in do_condition
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 822, in do_loop_tal
  Module zope.tales.tales, line 685, in setRepeat
  Module zope.tales.tales, line 101, in __init__
TypeError: iteration over non-sequence
```

My question is how do I change my template to get this working.  The template file used by the BrowserView is a close match to the original and defines a main macro.  I'm pretty sure there is no problem with it as if I replace it with the following blank template I still get exactly the same error.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
      xmlns:tal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal"
      xmlns:metal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/metal"
      xmlns:i18n="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/i18n"
      lang="en"
      metal:use-macro="context/main_template/macros/master"
      i18n:domain="plone">
<body>
<div metal:fill-slot="main">
    <tal:main-macro metal:define-macro="main">
    </tal:main-macro>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Using Products.PDBDebugMode I can debug further and find

```
TypeError: iteration over non-sequence
> c:\plone\parts\zope2\lib\python\zope\tales\tales.py(101)__init__()
-> self._iter = i = iter(seq)
(Pdb) a
self = <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.PathIterator object at 0x0B2FE350>
name = vdata
seq = <Products.CMFEditions.ZVCStorageTool.ShadowHistory object at 0x0B28C370>
context = <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.ZopeContext object at 0x0B2E3DD0>
```

seq here has no **iter** or **getitem** method and so iter() raises a TypeError.  This error is originating from the versions_history_form.pt

```
<tal:block repeat="vdata history">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry looks like this is a bug in my code rather than anything else.  I was overriding the template and the bug was originating in the bit of code where the override was - I hadn't synchronized changes in Plone 3.3.6 correctly.

This question should probably be deleted

Answer (score 2):

This error is not the same error as the one in that Plone bug.  This is happening because you have a `tal:repeat` somewhere that is trying to loop over something that isn't a sequence (or some other iterator).

Comment: I understand it is not the same error - that's why I posted the traceback.  I don't have a tal:repeat in my template and the traceback is not helpful.  I've tried stripping out everything in my template inside the main macro and still get the error.

Comment: The error is the one I describe, so somewhere in the rendering of your template, which *includes* the rendering of macros, it's tyring to loop over something that isn't an iterator.  That's what you need to find.

Comment: OK so if I set my template to this I still get the error:

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
          xmlns:tal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal"
          xmlns:metal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/metal"
          xmlns:i18n="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/i18n"
          lang="en"
          metal:use-macro="context/main_template/macros/master"
          i18n:domain="plone">
    <body>
    <div metal:fill-slot="main">
        <tal:main-macro metal:define-macro="main">
        </tal:main-macro>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>

Comment: Note in my last comment I said "which includes the rendering of macros".  You're still using a macro, which is still executing a `tal:repeat` somewhere on an invalid value.

Comment: Sorry I'm lost.  The only macro I have defined in my template is "main".  I believe this is the macro the versions_history_form is executing when it calls <metal:use_body use-macro="view_macro" /> . I've altered "main" so it includes precisely no code and still get the error.  To me this implies the bug lies in the plone core.  I don't mind trying to locate the bug but don't know where to start as the stack trace is really unhelpful.  If you could provide me with some pointers on how to debug then I'm happy to try

Comment: When you do `metal:use-macro="context/main_template/macros/master"` that includes precisely a *bunch* of code.  :-)  If you want to debug further, you could take a look at PDBDebugMode.  As for whether the bug is in Plone core, this is a different error than the bug you linked and there's no way without further information to assert that this "implies a bug in Plone core".  But if you're reporting a bug, this isn't the place.

Comment: OK thanks for the tip Ross.  I've debugged further and located the source of the error and added this above.